# How to Escape Obsidian Box in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been playing on an anarchy realm lately, and after stealing an enchanted book to put on my sword, I ended up being forced into a prison. Here are the main issues:

1. I have *constant mining fatigue*, due to being next to an ocean monument.
2. I have no items in my inventory of any kind.
3. The entire cell is made of obsidian; no other blocks.
4. No one is willing to come break me out because I am on no team.
5. I didn't set my spawn, but the server is on normal mode, so I can't starve to death.

My biggest question is **whether is any way I could possibly glitch through blocks or find a way to die?** I am playing Minecraft Bedrock Edition on the latest version.

Comment: did you set your spawn?

Comment: Sounds like you broke the rules and are dealing with the consequences. They haven't banned you from joining, so it sounds like your options are to either serve your sentence per the Realm's rules, or find another realm and don't repeat your mistakes.

Comment: Damn, you're in a pickle. 250s regular obsidian breaking speed with a fist, mining fatigue III = 370.3x multiplier, that's over 25 hours to break one block. This is why you don't visit unknown Nether portals without chorus fruit on Anarchy servers.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf you do know what an anarchy server is, right?

Comment: I don't, that's why I didn't leave an answer. But inferring from OPs post, they wouldn't have mentioned stealing an enchanted item if there wasn't some rule against that?

Comment: Are you able to /kill? I assume cheats are off, but it may be worth a try. You can also use the chat to ask for help? I'm not sure what the chat rules are on your server.

Comment: @Potterton Nope. It’s pure survival.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf an anarchy server by definition has no rules. Most likely the OP stole the item from a player with obsidian and this was retaliation

Comment: @RayWu Yep! That’s exactly what happened. 

Comment: @Kaizerwolf anarchy means no rules or chaos, this means ***players*** do anything they want and even enforce rules sometimes, not server admins, sometimes players enforce things against the server admin(see  2b2t's NSN and DSD) I could create an empire on 2b2t and enforce a no stealing rule, but people wouldnt be banned for that (well book banning chunk banning and boatbanning allow players to ban users, so op is lucky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ask for help, though on an anarchy server this could get you in even more trouble. Maybe ask someone you know IRL to join and help you out? You could also use an auto clicker or rig up your mouse/controller to continuously break obsidian for 25 hours per block if possible, but this will mean not being able to use your device for 50+ hours. It gets even more difficult on an iPhone. Otherwise you could try and find some reliable haste hack, considering it’s an anarchy server. Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Given your circumstances, here's a possible way on breaking out without help.

You specified the server is on normal mode, but you can actually starve to death there. Basically, just run and jump until you lose as much hunger as possible. It is more faster to jump-run if you are in a cell with a 2 block height area.

Given enough time, you will starve to death and you can respawn and break out easily.

I know you already broke out, but this could've been an option you can use to get out. Yes, it is a slow and painful death, but it is manageable. Continue being AFK without actually heating up your switch too much and let yourself die.